# iPhone 5S starts playing music by itself

Tags: iphone, music

I sometimes put my headphones in and find that music is already playing - I can usually tell how long it's been playing for depending on where I was last up to. Same for podcasts.

I've wracked my brain to figure out why this is happening. I thought at one point I may be accidentally bumping the play button on the headphone cable but I'm fairly confident I've ruled that out.

One thing that seems to trigger it is doing a touch id unlock after leaving the phone alone for a minute or so.

Has anyone else figured out what's going on?

Comment: It may be that the remote on your headphones is failing, sending random `play` commands to your iPod. Can you replace them? Does it ever happen without headphones plugged in?

Comment: try using headphones with out a play/pause button then you can rule out for sure if that is the issue.